# Let G act on itself by Conjugation. Prove Stab(g)=C(g)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to work my way through a few problems to better my understanding of the concepts involved in this proof:

Let G act on G by conjugation. Let $g \in G$. Prove that C(g)=Stab(g)

where C(g) means the centralizer of g and stab(g) is the stabilizer of g.

I know:

C(g)={$h \in G |hg=gh$}

Stab(g)={$x \in G|xg=g$} (since G is acting on itself here)

and here we must have that:

for some $x,g \in G: gx=gxg^{-1} $ since G acts on itself by conjugation.

I'm really not sure how to start. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Just show that $h g = g h$ iff $g h g^{-1} = h$.

Comment: When you write $x\cdot g=xgx^{-1}$, note that the products are different.  Also, I think that you should have $x$ acting on $g$, not $g$ acting on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $g^{-1}hg=h$ iff $hg=gh$.